# Android Studio Fails to open after installed "Failed to initialize graphics environment"

Tags: android, android-studio, java, ubuntu-16.04

I re-purposed an old laptop to experiment w/ some android apps; but after I've loaded Android Studio it fails to run with the following errors

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
No protocol specified

> Start Failed: Internal Error. Failed to initialize graphics
>   environment
>
> java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as
>   the value of the DISPLAY variable.    at
>   sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)     at
>   sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
>     at
>   sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
>     at
>   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
>     at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.(XToolkit.java:126)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)  at
>   java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)  at
>   java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1734)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(EventQueue.java:1043)    at
>   javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(SwingUtilities.java:1361)
>     at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.reclaim(StyleContext.java:454)     at
>   javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:311)     at
>   javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.addAttribute(StyleSheet.java:578)    at
>   javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:1501)
>     at
>   javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.setName(StyleContext.java:1312)
>     at
>   javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.(StyleContext.java:1259)
>     at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addStyle(StyleContext.java:107)    at
>   javax.swing.text.StyleContext.(StyleContext.java:87)    at
>   javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.(StyleSheet.java:166)  at
>   javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.getStyleSheet(HTMLEditorKit.java:391)
>     at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.(UIUtil.java:98)     at
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:73)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)    at
>   com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:113)

Details:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS;
64 bit;
Java versions:

> openjdk version "1.8.0_91" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Any thoughts?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? What do you see if you do `env | grep DISPLAY`?